# convergence test of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+4n+5} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+4n+5} $$

Can I say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+4n+5}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ and we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ converge for $\alpha>1$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Pedantically, you have to give an argument for $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2+4n+5} \leq \sum \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$. That's most easily done by the termwise inequality - which you're implicitly using, you just need to make it explicit.

Comment: @DanielFischer but does not $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverge?

Comment: Typo, @gbox, sorry. $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ of course.

Comment: maybe one could add that the denominator doesn't have any zeros so the terms of the sum are finite on any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}\geq1$. Together with ur argument about the behavior at infinity you should be done